# How to touch a file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file

In C#, what's the simplest/safest/shortest way to make a file appear as though it has been modified (i.e. change its last modified date) without changing the contents of the file?

Comment: Couldn't you just open the file and save the file?

Comment: @Anish, That sounds like not the simplest, safest, or fastest way to do that... (imagine if the code crashed in the middle of rewriting the file, or if the file was >= a couple of hundred megs in size...)

Answer (score 95):

```
System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(fileName, DateTime.UtcNow);
```

If you don't know whether the file exists, you can use this:

```
if(!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) 
    System.IO.File.Create(fileName).Close();   // close immediately 

System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(fileName, DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not create a file that doesn't already exist.

Comment: @EdwardNedHarvey it's not a problem at all:


    if(!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        System.IO.File.Create(fileName);
    System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(fileName, DateTime.UtcNow);

Comment: @coirius FYI... You'll want to make sure to close the stream created by File.Create.

Comment: There's a race condition that can occur between the `File.Exists` check and the `File.Create`, where a file could be created in the meantime, in which case the file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 7):

This works.  Could throw DirectoryNotFoundException, and various other exceptions thrown by File.Open()

```
public void Touch(string fileName)
{
    FileStream myFileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    myFileStream.Dispose();
    File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(fileName, DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `FileInfo`:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(file);
fi.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score -2):

Your solution with `System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc` will not let you touch the file, if the file is in use. A "hacky" way to touch a file that is in use would be to create your own touch.bat (since Windows doesn't have one like Linux does) and drop it to \windows\system32, so that you can invoke it from anywhere without specifying a full path.

The content of the touch.bat would then be (probably you can do it better without a temp file, this worked for me):

```
type nul > nothing.txt 
copy /B /Y nothing.txt+%1% > nul 
copy /B /Y nothing.txt %1% > nul 
del nothing.txt
```

**EDIT:** The following property can be set on a locked file:  `new FileInfo(filePath).LastWriteTime`

Comment: You should never put something in `%windir%\system32`. Instead you should modify your `PATH` environment variable to include the path where you put it.