# Is there a touch() for .NET/windows? can use while file is readlocked?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, windows, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to touch a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716484/how-to-touch-a-file-in-c)

Is there a touch() function available? I would like to update the timestamp so my script doesnt delete the file when it becomes X old. Another issue is it should work when the file is locked for reading by another process.

Comment: Updating the file timestamp can't be done when it's locked. Bit contradicting if you could?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the FileInfo class.  You can set LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime etc from there.

If the file is locked, you may run into a problem, but it's amazing what you CAN do to a locked file.